# hive:how to select all columns except column name 'cust_id' by regular expression

Tags: sql, hive

hive:how to select all columns except column name 'cust_id'by regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, update hive-site.xml with below configuration:

```
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
```

Now run the below query:

```
SELECT `(cust_id)?+.+` FROM <TABLE>;
```